# jQuery not stopping form from beign submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form that when submitted, if any field is empty id like to prevent the submission and add a class to the field.

For some reason I cant seem to get it too work, Ive added a fiddle, can anybody point out where im goign wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/yycqW/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your fiddle. Firstly, you haven't closed the `ready` event handler. Secondly, are passing `$this` into jQuery which is `undefined`. You need to pass `this` instead.

Finally, the form is always going to be submitted because you have to actually stop the submission. You can call the `preventDefault` method of the event object to do so. Here's a new version of your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        $('input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') { //Pass this into jQuery, not $this
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
                e.preventDefault(); //Stop the form from submitting
            }
        });              
    });
});
```

Also note that it's unnecessary to use `$(this).val()` inside the `each` loop. `this` will be a reference to a DOM element, and that element will have a `value` property, so it's more efficient to simply use `this.value`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not stopping the form from actually being submitted and thus it still gets posted (and thus immediately dropping your highlights). Try adding the [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method to your form and manually submit after checking for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from not calling `preventDefault`, you are using `$this` instead of `this` in one place and the brackets don't match.  Working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/yycqW/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(e, a) {
        $('input, textarea', this).each(function() {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
                e.preventDefault();
            } else($(this).hasClass('highlight')) ? $(this).removeClass('highlight') : false; // remove class on valid
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than  preventDefault(), returning false in the function that calls the form when submitted also prevents submitting. In the previous answer, let's think that there are more than one empty fields, preventDefault() will be unnecessarily fired more than once.

I would use something like this as a cleaner solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
            var submit=true; //A flag that we'll return
            $('input').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') { 
                    $(this).addClass('highlight');
                    submit=false //Setting the flag to false will prevent form to be  submitted
                }
            });
            return submit;  
    });
});
```